# Check request headers before sending 100 Continue

Tags: php

With PHP, is it possible to check the request headers on that request that contains `Expect: 100-Continue` within the request headers, before sending that `100 Continue` and then getting the actual request body?

That is, if someone wants to upload a file, I want to inspect the request headers and possibly reject the request before the client has to upload the whole thing.

Comment: Is your server written in php? or you are using apache (or some other server)?

Comment: @Dekel Is this behavior server-dependent?  Let's say Nginx running with PHP-FPM.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it's related, but it's important to know what/how exactly you are doing. btw, did you try to write something so it will be possible to run/debug? will be nice to see some code here...

Comment: @Dekel Not sure how to show code for something which as far as I know is impossible.  I don't need someone to write a full implementation for me, just need to know if it's possible and a general pointer.  (Such as `php://input`, but I don't think that solves my problem here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, your webservice (nginx or apache) will handle the 100-continue **before** triggering your PHP script, so there is nothing in PHP you can do to affect the result of that part of the HTTP protocol.

Your only solution would be to manually build a full HTTP server in PHP but that is not worth it.

If you control the client, you should simply use a HEAD request before making the actual request, that way you can handle the response in PHP.

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured.  Thanks!

Comment: @johnny do you know how to configure the nginx to handle the 100-continue and pass the next request with request body to the proxy server(assume API server)?